# How to call a file in /data/data with MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, media-player, midi

I want Android to play a song in /data/data/com.example.myapp/ called test3.mid

Do I need to put it in a subdirectory? Or am I calling setDataSource in a wrong way? The app crashes and gives me a NullPointerException.

```
try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("file://data/data/com.example.optimuse/test3");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I put it in the cache folder and it works now. Plus, I stupidly forgot the new command (since create() didn't seem to need it).

My working code:

I stored the file in the cache dir, that works!

```
File output = new File(getCacheDir() + "/exampleout.mid");
```

And then calling the file:

```
    String filePath = null;
    File file = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
try {
           filePath = getCacheDir() + "/exampleout.mid";
           file = new File(filePath);

           inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           if(inputStream.getFD().valid())
           {
               System.out.println("Valid!");
           }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

       try {
         mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If you have dropped your file directly on to your sd-card , then you can access it this way...

```
"/sdcard/test3.mp3"
```

**2.** But **above mentioned way is Not the proper way** to do it... **See below for the appropriate way.**

```
String baseDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "test3.mp3";
File f = new File(baseDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I use an emulator, so I don't want to use sdcard since that is not working in my emulator. How would I write a file in the app's directory (File output = new File(SOMETHING"test3.mid"); and play it from there?

Comment: You can try using the raw folder in your application